# Is a country name better stored as an integer/number in a database rather than a string containing it's name?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, sphinx

I'd like to know because I'm working on a search form and using thinking sphinx and for filtered attributes it seems like only integers are accepted but my countries are stored in the db as strings containing their names.

So I will be creating my own country list with strings to show in the select menu and values as integers to store in the db. Just wondering why the developer of the gem (ruby on rails) that I'm using decided to create an array containing just strings.

This question isn't programming language specific. A database is a database.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to have the countries in a separate table with an unique ID assigned to each of them. It makes no harm but really does make the database structure more flexible. This way you can add more information related to the countries in case you ever need to, and relate other tables to them, if you need to.

It might even be a performance issue to look up rows by a string. Querying another table to find the country ID's should not create too much pressure.

Comment: If performance is an issue to search against a table with little over 200 rows (ie. the number of countries) then adding an id won't solve the problem. Still, it is preferable to have a normalised model

Comment: So I would create a countries table and populate it with the countries and use each ID assigned to it to represent it. E.G. First country that hits the db would automatically get the id (1) and so on?

Comment: @GregoryHouse Yep. You can set your ID-column [`auto_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) to automate the ID increasement.

Comment: Sphinx indexing means that when users search and use the country filter to return users from a specific country my database will never be hit.

Answer (score 2):

of course the country name will always be string, just that whether directly use the country name as primary key, or use another column of integer as primary key

my stand is use the integer as primary key, so that update of country name later would be easier (even though unlikely but could happen). as for the problem of searching based on country name, just create an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a main lookup table with the integer mapping of a country would be better.
Then the country can be referenced in other tables as the country id(integer).

One  reason is when we try to access any data related to a country then comparing
the query country string against the actual string stored in DB is more expensive comparison as 
compared to comparing just two numbers.

Comment: Kind of depends on your access patterns. If we are (like in this case) searching against a country you might get better performance by doing id compares, but if most of your access is getting another row of data (by any means) it might be better to have just a textfield with on the same table as the other info (to avoid an extra join) and keeping all available countries in memory. It's a bit over 200 so it's quite acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store the countries in a separate table say id, name,short-name and then you can use its id for searching..

Answer (score -2):

My personal opinion is that it would fit more when storing country names as a string in a databese because country names do not change (usually) and there are no "updates" on them.

So i think it would be legit to store them as strings.

Comment: In my experience countries change all the time, South Sudan, for example is just over a year old. Whether or not it affects the system you're developing is another matter.

Comment: There is no reason to not save the countries in a separate table.

Comment: Yes i did not say that it would be wrong if you store it in a separate table - but it could also be a legit possibility. It Also depends on project size (if it is private or big commercial project...)